# Socket Read timeouts happening only with Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am load testing an external, third-party, API, with an initial qps of 2 requests per second. When I use JMeter, and run the test for 50 seconds, sending the requests directly to the API, I get an average response time of 4 seconds, with 0% failure rate, among all the 100 requests (this API needs some serious performance tuning, so I won't increase the load by now).

In other test scenario, I've set up a Spring Boot Rest application in front of this API, to repass the requests to the API using Apache Http client. But when I run the tests with the same load, pointing them to this app, I start to get socket read timeouts (they are configured to be 60s). In another implementation, not using Apache Http Client, and repassing the requests by hand, opening and closing a Java HttpsURLConnection, I get no read timeouts, and the results are consistent with sending the request directly, in the first scenario. Using http client, the timeouts starts to occur in the middle of the test, not in the first requests, and I get like 10% failure rate. I contacted the API developers, and it seems like there are no API errors on their side, but I could not debug this carefully with them yet. I am assuming it is some misconfiguration of Http Client, by now.

I configured Http Client with 30 workers per route, max 100 connections, and all timeouts (connect, connectionRequest, socket), to 60s.

Any ideas of what could be wrong?

**Edit:**

This is how I create the client:

```
@Bean
public CloseableHttpClient httpClient() {
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    cm.setMaxTotal(100);
    cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(30);

    SocketConfig socketConfig = SocketConfig.custom().setSoTimeout(60000).build();
    cm.setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig);

    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(60000)
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(60000)
            .setSocketTimeout(60000).build();

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(cm).setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
            .build();

    return httpclient;
}
```

Then, inside a service, I just call:

```
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    objectMapper.writeValue(writer, payloadObj);

    HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost(endpointString);
    httpRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpRequest.setEntity(new StringEntity(writer.toString(), "UTF-8"));

    try (CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpRequest)) {
        String rawResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

        // Do something with response

    }
```

**Edit:**

The Exception I am getting is:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:139)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:155)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:284)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
        at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
```

Comment: Show the code you have right now please

Comment: Can you show an example of the exception you're seeing on the client?  Also, you can turn up logging to see more details: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html